# Determine if a Selection Marquee is over a Rotated Rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I have a Rectangle class for drawing to HTML Canvas. It has a rotation property that gets applied in its draw method. If the user drags within the canvas, a selection marquee is being drawn. How can I set the Rectangle's `active` attribute to `true` when the Rectangle is within the selection marquee **using math**? This is a problem I'm having in another language & context so I do not have all of Canvas' methods available to me there (e.g. `isPointInPath`).

I found a StackOverflow post about finding [Mouse position within rotated rectangle in HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202006/mouse-position-within-rotated-rectangle-in-html5-canvas), which I am implementing in the Rectangle method `checkHit`. It doesn't account for the selection marquee, however. It's just looking at the mouse X & Y, which is still off. The light blue dot is the origin around which the rectangle is being rotated. Please let me know if anything is unclear. Thank you.

```js
class Rectangle
{
  constructor(x, y, width, height, rotation) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.xOffset = this.x + this.width/2;
    this.yOffset = this.y + ((this.y+this.height)/2);
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.active = false;
  }
  
  checkHit()
  {
    // translate mouse point values to origin
    let originX = this.xOffset;
    let originY = this.yOffset;
    let dx = marquee[2] - originX;
    let dy = marquee[3] - originY;
    // distance between the point and the center of the rectangle
    let h1 = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    let currA = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    // Angle of point rotated around origin of rectangle in opposition
    let newA = currA - this.rotation;
    // New position of mouse point when rotated
    let x2 = Math.cos(newA) * h1;
    let y2 = Math.sin(newA) * h1;
    // Check relative to center of rectangle
    if (x2 > -0.5 * this.width && x2 < 0.5 * this.width && y2 > -0.5 * this.height && y2 < 0.5 * this.height){
      this.active = true;
    } else {
      this.active = false;    
    }
    
  }
  
  draw()
  {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.xOffset, this.yOffset);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.rotate(this.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.translate(-this.xOffset, -this.yOffset);
    if (this.active)
    {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)';
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';      
    }
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.y+this.height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var raf;
var rect = new Rectangle(50,50,90,30,45);
var marquee = [-3,-3,-3,-3];
var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var offsetX=BB.left;
var offsetY=BB.top;
var start_x,start_y;

let draw = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //rect.rotation+=1;
  rect.draw();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.5)";
  ctx.fillRect(parseInt(marquee[0]),parseInt(marquee[1]),parseInt(marquee[2]),parseInt(marquee[3]))
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white"
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.rect(parseInt(marquee[0]),parseInt(marquee[1]),parseInt(marquee[2]),parseInt(marquee[3]))
  ctx.stroke()
  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

let dragStart = (e) =>
{
  start_x = parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  start_y = parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  marquee = [start_x,start_y,0,0];
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
}

let drag = (e) =>
{
  let mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  let mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  marquee[2] = mouseX - start_x;
    marquee[3] = mouseY - start_y;
  rect.checkHit();
}

let dragEnd = (e) =>
{
  marquee = [-10,-10,-10,-10];
  canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);

raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0;  
}

#canvas
{
  width: 360px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="360" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: You're looking to track transformations which is done mathematically with an affine transformation matrix. 1. Assign four x,y vertices to the untransformed rect. 2. Use matrix math to calc the transformed (eg rotated) vertices. 3. Draw the transformed rect. 4. To "hit-test" the rectangle, you invert the matrix to get the untransformed x,y marquee vertices. 5. Hit-test the untransformed marquee vs the original untransformed rect. Info about transformation matrices is readily available on SO & elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do convex polygons overlap

Rectangles are convex polygons.

`Rectangle` and `marquee` each have 4 points (corners) that define 4 edges (lines segments) connecting the points.

This solution works for all convex irregular polygons with 3 or more sides.

Points and edges must be sequential either Clockwise CW of Count Clockwise CCW

#### Test points

If any point of one poly is inside the other polygon then they must overlap. See example function `isInside`

To check if point is inside a polygon, get cross product of, edge start to the point as vector, and the edge as a vector.

If all cross products are >= 0 (to the left of) then there is overlap (for CW polygon). If polygon is CCW then if all cross products are <= 0  (to the right of) there is overlap.

It is possible to overlap without any points inside the other poly.

#### Test Edges

If any of the edges from one poly crosses any of the edges from the other then there must be overlap. The function `doLinesIntercept` returns true if two line segments intercept.

#### Complete test

Function `isPolyOver(poly1, poly2)` will return `true` if there is overlap of the two polys.

A polygon is defined by a set of `Point`'s and `Lines`'s connecting the points.

The polygon can be irregular, meaning that each edge can be any length > 0

Do not pass polygons with an edge of length === 0 or will not work.

#### Added

I added the function `Rectangle.toPoints` that transforms the rectangle and returning a set of 4 points (corners).

#### Example

Example is a copy of your code working using the above methods.

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

const Point = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x, y, set(x,y){ this.x = x; this.y = y }});
const Line = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});
const selector = { points: [Point(), Point(), Point(), Point()] }
selector.lines = [
    Line(selector.points[0], selector.points[1]),
    Line(selector.points[1], selector.points[2]),
    Line(selector.points[2], selector.points[3]),
    Line(selector.points[3], selector.points[0])
];
const rectangle = { points: [Point(), Point(), Point(), Point()] }
rectangle.lines = [
    Line(rectangle.points[0], rectangle.points[1]),
    Line(rectangle.points[1], rectangle.points[2]),
    Line(rectangle.points[2], rectangle.points[3]),
    Line(rectangle.points[3], rectangle.points[0])
];

function isInside(point, points) {
    var i = 0, p1 = points[points.length - 1];
    while (i < points.length) {
        const p2 = points[i++];
        if ((p2.x - p1.x) * (point.y - p1.y) - (p2.y - p1.y) * (point.x - p1.x) < 0) { return false }
        p1 = p2;
    }
    return true;
}
function doLinesIntercept(l1, l2) { 
    const v1x = l1.p2.x - l1.p1.x;
    const v1y = l1.p2.y - l1.p1.y;
    const v2x = l2.p2.x - l2.p1.x;
    const v2y = l2.p2.y - l2.p1.y;
    const c = v1x * v2y - v1y * v2x;
    if(c !== 0){
        const u = (v2x * (l1.p1.y - l2.p1.y) - v2y * (l1.p1.x - l2.p1.x)) / c;
        if(u >= 0 && u <= 1){
            const u = (v1x * (l1.p1.y - l2.p1.y) - v1y * (l1.p1.x - l2.p1.x)) / c;
            return  u >= 0 && u <= 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}   
function isPolyOver(p1, p2) { // is poly p2 under any part of poly p1
    if (p2.points.some(p => isInside(p, p1.points))) { return true };
    if (p1.points.some(p => isInside(p, p2.points))) { return true };
    return p1.lines.some(l1 => p2.lines.some(l2 => doLinesIntercept(l1, l2)));
}
    
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dragging = false;

const marquee = [0,0,0,0];
const rotate = 0.01;
var startX, startY, hasSize = false;
const BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const offsetX = BB.left;
const offsetY = BB.top;
class Rectangle {
    constructor(x, y, width, height, rotation) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.rotation = rotation;
        this.active = false;
    }
    toPoints(points = [Point(), Point(), Point(), Point()]) {
        const xAx = Math.cos(this.rotation) / 2;
        const xAy = Math.sin(this.rotation) / 2;
        const x = this.x, y = this.y;
        const w = this.width, h = this.height;
        points[0].set(-w * xAx + h * xAy + x, -w * xAy - h * xAx + y);
        points[1].set( w * xAx + h * xAy + x,  w * xAy - h * xAx + y);
        points[2].set( w * xAx - h * xAy + x,  w * xAy + h * xAx + y);
        points[3].set(-w * xAx - h * xAy + x, -w * xAy + h * xAx + y);
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, this.x, this.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.active ? 'rgba(255,0,0,1)' : 'rgba(0,0,255,1)';
        ctx.lineWidth = this.active ? 3 : 1;
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(-this.width / 2, - this.height / 2, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
function draw(){
    rect.rotation += rotate;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    rect.draw();
    drawSelector();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
function drawSelector() {
    if (dragging && hasSize) {
        rect.toPoints(rectangle.points);
        rect.active = isPolyOver(selector, rectangle);
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.5)";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(...marquee);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    
    } else {
        rect.active = false;
    }

 
}
function dragStart(e) {
    startX = e.clientX - offsetX;
    startY = e.clientY - offsetY;
    drag(e);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
    
}
function drag(e) {
    dragging = true;
    const x = e.clientX - offsetX;
    const y = e.clientY - offsetY;
    const left = Math.min(startX, x);
    const top = Math.min(startY, y);
    const w = Math.max(startX, x) - left;
    const h = Math.max(startY, y) - top;
    marquee[0] = left;
    marquee[1] = top;
    marquee[2] = w;
    marquee[3] = h;
    if (w > 0 || h > 0) {
        hasSize = true;
        selector.points[0].set(left,   top);
        selector.points[1].set(left + w, top);
        selector.points[2].set(left + w, top + h);
        selector.points[3].set(left  , top + h);
        
    } else {
        hasSize = false;
    }
}
function dragEnd(e) {
    dragging = false;
    rect.active = false;
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", drag);
}

const rect = new Rectangle(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 90, 90, Math.PI / 4);
```

```css
body
{
  margin:0;  
}

#canvas
{
  width: 360px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="360" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough answer. I've been doing my best to convert it to my other project and there's one part I'm not fully understanding: your explanation of the `isInside` function. "To check if point is inside a polygon, get cross product of, edge start to the point as vector, and the edge as a vector." What am I using to get the cross product? What does "edge start to the point as vector and the edge as a vector" mean? Thank you!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain A vector is an arrow.with direction and length. In 2D it is represented as two numbers, the x and y distance from the origin (0,0). To convert a line (with start and end points) into a vector you subtract the start coords from the end. Edge is a line, the "edge as a vector" is the edge start coord sub the edge end coord. "Edge start" is the start of line, "to point as vector", is the vector from the start of the edge to the point being tested. Here is a link to Ted-Ed video that does a good job of explaining vectors. https://ed.ted.com/lessons/what-is-a-vector-david-huynh